# Flutter web svg image will not be displayed after Firebase hosting

Tags: flutter-web

Svg images do not appear after hosting. Consolos scan shows that svg files are  downloaded. But it doesn't appear. Can anyone help me with this?

I have already built the web app in both html and canvaskit, but it doesn't work in either. I can only see the svg images on localhost.

I use the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg package.

I use a Firebase hosting service.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKKmd.png) => localhost

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jcx9.png) => hosting

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Nothing. I started using another package, but it's not good either, because it generates an image from svg and starts scaling it, which is the same as if I used a png image. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg_provider

Comment: I posted an answer for you. I fixed it here and maybe solve it on your side too. If you fix it, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to diplay the current svg/png correctly after Firebase Deploy.

There's something wrong with flutter after we run `flutter build web`. The respective assets, should be moved into `/web` directory (on build folder you can check items before do the deploy). But, they are not moved in.

So, in my case, I've removed all assets (png's or svg's) from the root project `/assets` and set them into the `/web/assets` folder (mannually)!

This is the automatic process that flutter do after you run `flutter build web`.

Just pay attention with the declaration of the assets in the pubspec.yaml file. The files must be matching the path for the web folder.

Example:

pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
    - assets/
```

using the svg icon (without the /assets):

```
 myIcon.svg
```

Try it. It should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try it and report back.

Comment: Great catch this solved my issue my build/web/assets/assets was empty i replaced it with my assets folder and worked thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to put the full path name (i.e. include 'assets/'):

```
SvgPicture.asset('assets/path/to/file.svg')
```

Comment: I use it in the same way, but it was still not good after hosting.